# Difference between inserto into in each line or just one per table

Tags: sql, insert, mysql, dump

I use two forms of backup on my clients table.
Sometimes I use the mysqldump and sometimes I use the SQLYog backup.

SQLYog creates the insert this way:

```
insert  into `tbb111`(`PPU_NOME_USU`,`PPU_NOME_PRG`,`PPU_SEQ_PRG`,`PPU_DES_PPU`) values ('RACHEL','SDMW','0','Todas     ;01012014;28022014;00001;;;');
insert  into `tbb111`(`PPU_NOME_USU`,`PPU_NOME_PRG`,`PPU_SEQ_PRG`,`PPU_DES_PPU`) values ('RACHEL','SDMW2251','0','01012013;31122014;');
insert  into `tbb111`(`PPU_NOME_USU`,`PPU_NOME_PRG`,`PPU_SEQ_PRG`,`PPU_DES_PPU`) values ('RACHEL','SDMW2290','0','Todos;01012013;31122014;;;;00000000000;99999999999;;');
```

And the mysqldump creates this way:

```
INSERT INTO `sdm638` VALUES 
('1','1','201402','1002','Computadores e Periféricos','0','0','222222','0','733.4800','539.3200','1272.8000','0.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0','0','0'), 
('1','1','201402','1008','Veículos','0','0','222222','0','0.0000','42900.0000','42900.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0','0','0'),
('1','1','201402','2001','Água e Esgoto','0','0','222222','0','458.6400','458.6400','917.2800','0.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0','0','0'),
('1','1','201402','2002','Combustível','0','0','222222','0','0.0000','237.6000','237.6000','0.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0','0','0'),
('1','1','201402','2004','Copa e Cozinha','0','0','222222','0','463.2000','181.6998','644.8998','0.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0.0000','0','0','0')
```

Mysqldump is obviously better since the file is a lot smaller.
I just tested on a client the mysqldump got 2.5gb while the SQLYog is 8gb.

I want to know whats the difference between them.The mysqldump will always work even without the insert into in every line?
Performance is the same or the mysqldump is faster since have less code?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally both are the same, but from the performance point of view the latter (mysqldump version) is much faster since parsing is not performed to every row but rather to a bunch of rows at once.

Recommended reading:

- [Speed of INSERT Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html)

Answer (score 0):

The important think in difference is:
In the fist one you make sure the data is correct. if you add some col to the table, you can be sure you add the values to the correspondent col. but this cost more bytes in the script

In the second you reduce the script in cost of bytes and the performance increase.

Becouse this is a backup i think your better choose is the mysqldump

Hope this help.